# Running ReportingService2010 with C# raises "Anonymous logon is not configured" error

Tags: c#, reporting-services

They have SQL Server Reporting Services 2016 and provided me with the admin username and password.

I want to deploy SSRS reports, data sources, folders from C# console application.

To do this, I have created `ReportingService2010` WebReference.

Now in my console application I do:

```
var rs = new ReportingService2010();

rs.Url = "https://ssrs-[my-server].com/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx";

rs.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "Pa$$word", "ssrs-[my-server].com");

var catalogItems = rs.ListChildren("/", false);
```

And on the last line I get the exception:

> Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'

The html contains a page with the following message

> Anonymous logon is not configured. userIdentity should not be null!

I noticed that when I want to sign into the SSRS web portal, it redirects me to

> **auth**-[my-server].com

where I enter the admin username and password, and then it redirects me back to

> **ssrs**-[my-server].com

Can this redirection to auth page and back be a sign why I can not make the regular C# code working?

Is it still OK to use `ReportingService2010` WebReference with SSRS 2016 or there other means already exist to deploy SSRS artefacts from C#?